# How do I enable PHP extensions on CentOS to finally finish installing/configuring Drupal?

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Drupal 8.0.5 (a standard profile) on Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7, with PHP 5.6.19.  But in the GUI, I get a problem on the requirements page.  It says "PHP extensions disabled.  Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list... gd"

I have installed, with yum install these packages: gd, gd-devel, php-gd, php-pdo php-mbstring, php-xml.

I have installed various other packages.  I have no reason to think that PHP gd extensions have not been enabled.  They've certainly been installed.  I've restarted Apache services and MariaDB services. I've rebooted the sever.

I reinstalled Drupal and PHP.  I created a php.ini file with "extension=gd.so" as the content.  A minimal installation fails for the same reason.

What should I do to get Drupal working for the first time?  I have never done this before.  How do I enable the PHP Extensions?  Or is the message false?  If it is, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS, you should have an icon in cPanel for "PHP Selector":

[image: PHP Selector]

In CloudLinux:

[image: PHP Selector]

Make sure all of the PHP extensions installed by Yum are enabled & save the settings. Then create or open the [info.php page](https://www.hostwinds.com/guide/create-php-info-page/) for your domain to confirm the configuration. The problem should be fixed on the Drupal 8 status report.

Note: If you are having problems with installing PHP extensions for a web server running Drupal, consider [installing Composer on CentOS](https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-install-php-composer-on-a-centos-7-vps-or-dedicated-server/). Composer is designed to streamline dependency management in PHP and manages the particular download files required by Drupal 8 modules specifically.

Comment: Composer manages PHP code dependencies, but the original question asks for PHP extensions (those are parts of PHP itself). So using composer is not going to help installing PHP extensions in the system.